# Javascript - wait for 1 minute for every 10 loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

How can I wait for 1 or 2 minute for every 10 loop?

For instance, this is my working code:

```
var dates = ["2016-08-31T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-01T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-02T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-03T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-04T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-05T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-06T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-07T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-08T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-09T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-10T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-12T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-13T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-14T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-15T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-16T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-17T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-18T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-19T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-20T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-21T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-22T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-23T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-24T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-25T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-26T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-27T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-28T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-29T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-30T23:00:00.000Z","2016-10-01T23:00:00.000Z"];

var counter = 0;

// Loop the dates and convert them to this format: yyyy-m-d
dates.forEach(function(date, index) {
    counter ++;

    console.log(date);

    // Reset when you reach 10 counts.
    if (counter === 10) {
        counter = 0;
    }

    // Wait for 2 minute before the next 10 loop.
    setTimeout( function() {
       //
    }, 120000);
});
```

Is it possible? Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

What I am after:

```
2016-08-31T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-01T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-02T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-03T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-04T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-05T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-06T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-07T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-08T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-09T23:00:00.000Z

(wait for 2 minute here)

2016-09-10T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-12T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-13T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-14T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-15T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-16T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-17T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-18T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-19T23:00:00.000Z

(wait for 2 minute here)

2016-09-20T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-21T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-22T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-23T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-24T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-25T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-26T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-27T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-28T23:00:00.000Z
2016-09-29T23:00:00.000Z

(wait for 2 minute here)

2016-09-30T23:00:00.000Z
2016-10-01T23:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Where is the `counter` variable being defined and what is it's value?

Comment: @Ionut i updated my question. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` and inside just `for` loop to increment by 10 in each interval.

```js
var dates = ["2016-08-31T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-01T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-02T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-03T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-04T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-05T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-06T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-07T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-08T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-09T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-10T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-12T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-13T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-14T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-15T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-16T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-17T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-18T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-19T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-20T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-21T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-22T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-23T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-24T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-25T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-26T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-27T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-28T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-29T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-30T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-10-01T23:00:00.000Z"];
var c = 0
var time = 2000; // 2 sec just for demo

function loopDates() {
  for (var i = c; i < c + 10; i++) {
    if (dates[i]) {
      var date = dates[i].slice(0, 10);
      console.log(date)
    }
  }
  c += 10

  if (c >= dates.length) clearInterval(x)
}

loopDates()
var x = setInterval(loopDates, time)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer!. is this waiting 2 secs in the first 10 as well?

Comment: @teelou I updated my answer, you could take out function and just call it first.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the function you do want to execute once per minute inside the setTimeout function. Also if you want to execute more than once, you should replace setTimeout with setInterval

```
setInterval( function() {
   dates.forEach(function(date, index) {
      counter ++;

      // Reset when you reach 10 counts.
      if (counter === 10) {
       counter = 0;
      }
   }
}, 120000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have variable for the time in timeout. Set its value to 120000 when your counter reaches 10. And make sure that you are enclosing settimeout inside IIFE (immediately invoked function expression). So for that time for particular index it'll wait for 2 minutes & then continues the loop with next indexes.

Comment: any examples please?