# JavaScript - dispatch 10 promises in every minute?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

How can I dispatch 10 promises in every minute?

I have these dynamic dates in a list:

```
var dates = ["2016-08-31T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-01T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-02T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-03T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-04T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-05T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-06T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-07T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-08T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-09T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-10T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-12T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-13T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-14T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-15T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-16T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-17T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-18T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-19T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-20T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-21T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-22T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-23T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-24T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-25T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-26T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-27T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-28T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-29T23:00:00.000Z","2016-09-30T23:00:00.000Z","2016-10-01T23:00:00.000Z"];
```

I want to get the content or result that associated with these dates. But I don't want to get them in one go, but every 10 items in every minute, until the date is no more.

This is my working code:

```
     var promises = dates.map(function (date, i) {
        return getContent(date);
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
    });
```

It gets the content in a row, not exactly what I want.

But is it possible to achieve what I need? Any ideas?

**Notes:**

`getContent(date)` contains a massive of `async await` promises, so in that `promse.all` that calls it has to be a `promise` too i guess, otherwise I can get all return data in one place (which is `console.log(data);`) when the promises end.

**EDIT:**

```
const delayValue = (val, ms) => {
    new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, val), ms)
    });
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use promises for this if the amount of data per minute really matters. I would just use `setInterval` and clear the interval after all data is gone.

Comment: Promises aren't for doing work over time, they are for handling doing something once some work has completed. And possibly doing something different depending on the outcome of that work. I would rethink your code and what you are actually trying to achieve. Even the answer below is just a hack to get promises doing what you want which they arent meant to do.

Comment: *"every 10 items in every minute, until the date is no more"*: I don't understand this phrase. Can you work out an example?

Comment: @trincot I think they mean they have an array of data, they want to do something with each index every 6 seconds until the data is gone.

Comment: @trincot this is what I mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944653/javascript-wait-for-1-minute-for-every-10-loop I can achieve it with that answer in that question but it does not give what `promise.all` can give us.

Comment: Is the array dynamic in the sense that during the time you process the array, it may grow? To illustrate, let's say you've processed 20 items in the array over 2 minutes, but during that time, an additional 6 elements was added to the array. Also, is the `getContent()` function doing *asynchronous* work (e.g waiting for I/O; HTTP requests, database calls, etc)?

Comment: @Svenskunganka dynamic - i mean it may have 100 dates in the array. but I will set it manually before running them in `promises`.

Comment: @teelou Then it is static. I will not grow during the time you process the dates, then?

Comment: @Svenskunganka yes it will not. it is just one-off thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Promise only resolves once, so if you need to have results every minute, *and* want to do this with promises, you'll need to have a separate promise per chunk of data.

Here is how you could do that by repeatedly creating a promise with a custom `delayValue` function:

```js
const delayValue = (val, ms) => 
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, val), ms));

async function loopDates(dates, chunk, delay) {
    for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i += chunk) {
        console.log(await delayValue(dates.slice(i, i+chunk), i ? delay : 0));
    }
}

var dates = ["2016-08-31T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-01T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-02T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-03T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-04T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-05T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-06T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-07T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-08T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-09T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-10T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-12T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-13T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-14T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-15T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-16T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-17T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-18T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-19T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-20T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-21T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-22T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-23T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-24T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-25T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-26T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-27T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-28T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-29T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-30T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-10-01T23:00:00.000Z"];

loopDates(dates, 10, 2000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Now to add the `getContent` factor into it, you would do the `map` like you did (although the syntax can be shortened), and then apply `Promise.all` on each chunk:

```js
const delayValue = (val, ms) => 
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, val), ms));

// Mock for getContent:
const getContent = date => Promise.resolve(date);
    
async function loopDates(dates, chunk, delay) {
    const promises = dates.map(getContent);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i += chunk) {
        console.log(await delayValue(Promise.all(promises.slice(i, i+chunk)), 
                                     i ? delay : 0));
    }
}

var dates = ["2016-08-31T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-01T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-02T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-03T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-04T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-05T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-06T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-07T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-08T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-09T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-10T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-12T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-13T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-14T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-15T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-16T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-17T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-18T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-19T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-20T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-21T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-22T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-23T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-24T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-25T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-26T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-27T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-28T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-29T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-09-30T23:00:00.000Z", "2016-10-01T23:00:00.000Z"];

loopDates(dates, 10, 2000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Sorry i have a question on this `const delayValue = (val, ms) => 
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, val), ms));` - why can't I have brackets around it? I will get `undefined` if I do that. See my edit above. thanks.

Comment: Arrow functions have two syntaxes: I used the expression syntax, where the expression is the returned value. If you add *braces* then you turn to the statement block syntax: in that case you must use `return` before the expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you are insisting on using promises then, create a promise with a set timeout resolver.

Inside pop the array and do whatever you like. Promise all of an array of those promises would do the trick I think.

But why promises rather than a simple for loop with set timeout?

Comment: `getContent(date)` contains a massive of `async await` promises. so in that bit that call it has to be a promise too i guess. but it seems that not possible to chunk it.